# How to get state item in canvas

Tags: canvas, tcl

I am looking to get only the items having a 'normal state', I traced different line with different states (hidden and normal),
Actually I use :

```
foreach itemId [.c find all]
...
```

I tried like this but It does'nt work

```
set state [.c itemcget $tag state]
set state [$itemId cget state]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item in a canvas can have three difference states, namely normal, disabled or hidden. That's true, except that the state for an item created without specifying the state, in the sense that this item does not have any state.

If you create an item with state normal, you would do:

```
.c create item -state normal
```

Let's say that this item has the ID 1. Doing `.c itemcget 1 -state` would give you `normal`.

If you create another item without specifying the state...

```
.c create item
```

and supposing it has ID 2, then doing `.c itemcget 1 -state` will give you an empty string.

Essentially, normal and 'nothing' are the same. You can see all the options of a particular item with:

```
.c itemconfigure tagOrId
```

And for the case of item 1, you would notice that you have `-state {} {} {} {normal}` and for item 2, you would have `-state {} {} {} {}`.

In conclusion, to get a list of all item IDs with normal state, you could do:

```
set normalItems [list]
foreach itemId [.c find all] {
    set state [.c itemcget $itemId -state]
    if {$state eq "" || $state eq "normal"} {
        lappend normalItems $itemId
    }
}
```

Or use `$state in {"" "normal"}` if you want to make the if condition shorter.

Note: `pathName cget state` is used to get the state of the canvas, not the item within the canvas.